# Same position in a list?

Tags: python

```
words = ['me','me']
def nth_char(words):
    newArray = []
    for i in words:
        x = words.index(i)
        newArray.append(x)
    return newArray
```

instead of [0,1] I get [0,0], why???
is there any other easier way of doing this?
I am new in programming so any help if welcome

Comment: `index` returns the index to the **first** element it finds, in case of elements appearing multiple times.

Comment: What exactly is this function supposed to do?

Comment: That's because *index* looks for the first occurrence in the list and, in your case, it's always at index zero

Comment: An instance of `list` does not keep track of what previous calls to `index` have returned, because as the list changes, those values may no longer have any meaning.

Comment: So, for every word you want its current index while iterating. That seems very odd! `return range(len(words))` would do that... Pls elaborate in prose what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Or iterate over `enumerate(words)`, which gives you a sequence of list elements paired with their index.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
words = ['me','me']
def nth_char(words):
    newArray = []
    for index, element in enumerate(words):
        newArray.append(index)
    return newArray
```